# What is the normal rate of failing to submit a block from pool mining Electroneum

Tags: mining, mining-pools

We have a node-cryptonote-pool mining Electroneum, and sometimes it even finds a block.

However, due to many factors, most of which are obscure for me, it fails to submit it, fails with error like this:

```
Error submitting block at height 141295 from here-goes-wallet-address@127.0.0.1, share type: "trusted" - {"code":-7,"message":"Block not accepted"}`
```

Sometimes it just does not have this `{"code":-7,"message":"Block not accepted"}` block.

The electroneumd (fork of monerod) shows error `Transaction not found in pool` at the same time.

We lose ~50% of mined blocks with such errors.
The question is, what is the normal rate for such errors? Is 50% indeed normal and what we can do is just to give up and live with it, or there is a room for improvement?

I ask here on Monero stackexchange because I did not find Electroneum-related site, and Electroneum is a fork of Monero. Also, Monero had the similar block time of 1 minute as ETN has now, so maybe some "older" pool owners mining Monero might help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because electroneum

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the normal rate is but since i started mining a week ago, i rarely get a rejected-messages. Not sure if that has todo with your mining software, your hardware or the pool but to at least exclude the pool, see if another pool works better for you.

Currently i mine at [Coinfoundry](https://coinfoundry.org) which is a really new pool that supports also Electroneum and has a fee of 0.15% (it will never have a higher fee then 0.6%) and no other costs. Try it. If that doesn't help you, then you at least know that that's not the problem.